# Using Redux Provider vs Redux Wrapper with NextJs | State Persists Without Wrapper

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

According to the [docs](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) for the next-redux-wrapper:

> When Next.js static site generator or server side rendering is involved, however, things start to get complicated as another store instance is needed on the server to render Redux-connected components.

I don't understand exactly where the complication arises.

### SSR to SSG Redux State Persists During Page Navigation

I built a simple NextJs app that has one page that renders on the server, and another that is statically rendered. In production mode or in development mode, I can navigate between these two pages, and my redux state remains in-tact.

My understanding is that this isn't supposed to be the case, since a separate redux store must be created on the server and on the client; hence the creation of the next redux wrapper (also for injecting redux state into NextJs lifecycle methods, which I haven't needed).

I'm confused as to what mechanism is being used to persist the redux state between SSR and SSG pages. I'm using a simple redux provider, with a simple bit of state for testing.

**Note:** State persists between these two page components even *without* using redux-persist.

### Redux Persist Also Works...

I have confirmed that redux persist also works without the next redux wrapper, saving to the local storage without issue, persisting successfully on page refresh.

Here's example code of my configuration:

**page1.js (Statically rendered)**

```
import Layout from './layout';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getTest, addBar } from '../redux/slices/topten';

export default function Page1() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const myState = useSelector(getTest);

  return (
    <Layout>
        <h2>Statically Rendered</h2>
        <div>
           <span>
             { myState }
           </span>
           <button onClick={() => dispatch(addBar())}>
              Add Bar to Foo
           </button>
        </div>
    </Layout>
   )
}
```

**page2.js (Server-side rendered)**

```
import Layout from './layout';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getTest, addBar } from '../redux/slices/topten';

export default function Page2() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const myState = useSelector(getTest);

    return (
       <Layout>
            <h2>Server Side Rendered</h2>
            <div>
                <span>
                    { myState }
                </span>
                <button onClick={() => dispatch(addBar())}>
                    Add Bar to Foo
                </button>
            </div>
       </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {

   // Code for fetching data from external api.

  return {
    props: {
        // Returned props
    }
  };
};
```

**App.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { store, persistor } from '../redux/store';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PersistGate> 
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

**topten.js (This is the redux slice with a simple reducer)**

```
const initialState = {
    topTen: {
        test: "foo"
    }
}

const topTenSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'topten',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addBar: (state) => {
            state.topTen.test = "foobar";
        }
    },
});

// Export action.
export const { addBar } = topTenSlice.actions;


// Export slice reducer.
export default topTenSlice.reducer;

// Export state.
export const getTest = state => state.topten.topTen.test;
```

I left out the code for Layout and store, because it's redundant. It works without the wrapper... That's what I'm trying to understand.

I have verified here that state persists between the two components simply using the Provider HOC. According to the docs:

> store is being replaced on navigation

I have also verified that state is persisting on page refresh using redux-persist.

I don't understand why I would need the wrapper unless I needed access to redux state within the NextJs lifecycle methods... Which can easily be avoided using redux `useSelector` hooks.

Any clarity on this would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question, but it's a good applicable read :) https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/server-components

Comment: You're fetching the data on the client-side, the complications arise when the data is fetched on the server inside Next.js data fetching methods (`getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`) and the state needs to be synched between server and client.

Comment: @juliomalves Actually, my data is being fetched on the server. I can log it in the console in my terminal, and it is being rendered server-side which I verified by the HTML output in the browser.

Comment: Can you provide the code that's fetching the data on the server-side? The code you provided so far seems to be fetching the data inside a `useEffect` which only runs on the client.

Comment: @juliomalves I added code, along with a more accurate description of the issue.